# how can I clean my linseed treated wooden doors?

Tags: wood, doors

My beautiful Knotty Alder patio doors appear that dirt or mold has penetrated the linseed oil we applied to them before hanging them. How can I clean the doors? What should I use to clean them?

Answer (score 1):

Removing linseed oil from wood doors is not a difficult process. Simply apply turpentine to the doors with a rag in a circular motion until the linseed oil starts to dissolve. Let the turpentine sit for 10 to 20 minutes. then wash them down with warm, soapy water.

Answer (score 0):

Turpentine, mineral spirits, or the vaguely termed "paint thinner" should be effective at stripping the oil from the door.

Linseed oil is prone to developing mold and mildew, you may want to consider refinishing with a product meant for outdoors (I wouldn't recommend spar varnish if it's exposed to direct sunlight though).